# Set Redis cache prefix key on Symfony

Tags: symfony, caching, redis

I'm using Redis to manage some caching within my Symfony 3.4 app, configured like this:

**config.yml**

```
framework:
    cache:
        default_redis_provider: 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379'
        pools:
            cache.catalog:
                adapter: cache.adapter.redis
                provider: iwid.custom_redis_provider
                default_lifetime: 86400
                public: true
            cache.language:
                adapter: cache.adapter.redis
                provider: iwid.custom_redis_provider
                default_lifetime: 86400
                public: true
```

**services.yml**

```
services:
    iwid.custom_redis_provider:
        class: Redis
        factory: ['Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\RedisAdapter', 'createConnection']
        arguments:
            - 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379'
            - { retry_interval: 0, timeout: 30 }
```

Now, this is working like a charm in dev and prod environments, except for one thing in production: when I deploy a new release, my deployer system **creates a new folder** and **git pull** inside it, then **target this folder as the current rootdir** with a symlink.

Then, when I deploy any release, the prefix of my Redis keys is changed, as the path to my app is different. Then, this obviously invalidate any previously cached keys... which is not what I want!

So, ho can I change this, probably by having a sort of "fixed" cache key (one for each pool obviously).

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes you have to set a fixed key (as they said in the [Symfony Doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#prefix-seed)).

You can use also the environment name (dev, staging, prod... - `SYMFONY_ENV` or `APP_ENV`) with the application name if you want to use the same Redis cluster for staging and prod for example.

```
framework:
    cache:
        ...
        prefix_seed: '%kernel.environment%_myapp'
        ...
```