# How to autowire 2 symfony services, which use the same interface and addtional arguments

Tags: yaml, symfony5.4

I have two services, which both use the same interface and one is injected in the other.
With this configuration in the service.yaml everything worked well:

```yaml
    # fix autowiring for 2 services using the same interface
    App\Domain\ListService: ~
    App\Domain\SapService\SapListService: ~
    
    App\Domain\ListService $sapListService: '@App\Domain\SapService\SapListService'
    App\Domain\ListServiceInterface: '@App\Domain\ListService'
```

following the official documentation found [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/autowiring.html#dealing-with-multiple-implementations-of-the-same-type).

Now one of my services needs the information in which environment the class is currently running.

In a simple service configuration I would write it like this:

```yaml
    App\Service\FooService:
        arguments:
            $env: '%env(APP_ENV)%'
```

But how do I add the environment information in my more complex situation?

I tried this:

```yaml
    App\Domain\ListService: ~
    App\Domain\SapService\SapListService: ~

    App\Domain\ListService $sapListService: '@App\Domain\SapService\SapListService'
        arguments:
            $env: '%env(APP_ENV)%'
    App\Domain\ListServiceInterface: '@App\Domain\ListService'
```

which throws this error:

```bash
The file "/var/www/src/../config/services.yaml" does not contain valid YAML: Unable to parse at line 52 (near "    arguments:").
```

**What is the proper formatting to parse the environment information into my service?**

I tried manual wiring like this:

```php
    public function __construct(
        ListServiceInterface $sapListService,
        #[Autowire('%env(APP_ENV)%')]
        string $env
    ) {
        $this->sapListService = $sapListService;
        $this->env = $env;
    }
```

which gives me the error:

```bash
In DefinitionErrorExceptionPass.php line 54:

  Cannot autowire service "App\Domain\ListService": argument "$env" of method "__construct()" is type-hinted "string", you should configure its
   value explicitly.
```

Looks like the Autowire annotation is only available with symfony 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the namespace in the redis config to separate the different environments and not use the APP_ENV var to create the keys to store.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the best solution is to prefix the cache key with the environment via the cache configuration in the cache.yaml file.

The solution is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58388780/set-redis-cache-prefix-key-on-symfony)